# cordova/exec fails within meteor project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

After building a Cordova plugin with `plugman`, installing it in meteor 2.3.2 and running `meteor run android-build`, I get the following error from within the plugin:

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "cordova/exec" in ~/MeteorApp/MyPlugin/www/MyPlugin.js (web.browser)
```

The error line is from line 2 in the generate MyPlugin.js

```js
// ~/MeteorApp/MyPlugin/www/MyPlugin.js


// I added this check for cordova myself

if (cordova && cordova.exec ) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');
    exports.coolMethod = function (arg0, success, error) {
        exec(success, error, 'MyPlugin', 'coolMethod', [arg0]);
    };
}
```

My meteor structure includes the plugin folder at the route of the app

I installed the package using `meteor add cordova:my.plugin.id@file://path/to/plugin/project`

Cordova version 10.0.8

I have the following plugin structure:

```sh
pluginDir/
   src/
      android/
         MyPlugin.java
   www/
      MyPlugin.js
   package.json
   plugin.xml
```

I have tested the plugin inside a Cordova app and that works just fine.

I bet the issue here is how meteor exposes the internal Cordova object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Meteor already wraps the cordova object so really instead of importing cordova/exec in the /www plugin definition I simply had to use `cordova.exec('my logic goes here')`

The above is scaffolded with `plugman` and the /www folder and files get generated automatically, as well as the above code.

The code above is valid within Cordova, but this logic fails within Meteor.

### Extra comments

Only Android support was required for this plugin and the `cordova.exec()` logic was moved into a Meteor api method.

Because of this Android-only requirement the /www folder and references was removed.

The /www folder may be reintroduced in the future in order to define a nice fallback for web usage scenarios, but it's unlikely for our internal plugin.